# How can I replace `UITableViewCell` with a `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` after the main `UITableView` is already loaded?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I am messing around with how this feels in my app.  I have a `UITableView` and I have the swiping/panning in place, where I kind of flick the cell away and once the cell is away I have it call a method in the same class where I have my `UITableView` as a property.  Once that cell is swiped away and that method gets called, I want to animate the size of the now empty cell to be about 3 times the size of the cell and have a `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` be added.  It will be a place to store all comments about that cell.

Basically, I would just like some ideas on how I can replace a swiped cell with a `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` and animate it to three times the size of any cell.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, if the text below is **tl;dr**:

call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, remember which cell you've changed, update `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` accordingly, and you are set to go.

Full version:

When you said *swiped away*, did you meant that you are reloading or deleting certain row of your `UITableView`?

If so, I think you might be able to do what you described by calling `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];` (or whatever direction you'd like), then saving the indexPaths you've changed (in your case only one indexPath), and react appropriately in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dataSource method - changing the normal cell for another one, custom-made, with `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` inside, and also reacting in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, to change the height.

The animation itself will be handled by tableView, so that's an ease for you.

Also, if you will use this method to change the contents of the cell for `UITableView`, don't forget to assign delegate and dataSource of that cell's new tableView, since that causes lot of troubles when forgot.